# Error happens when using the UIImageViewPicker Control in ios5.0

Tags: iphone

I have the following code fragment that I use to use photo library in device 
 It works well in ios7.0

But in ios5.0, when calling this part, my App release following errors
The building is succeeded and other operations work well
But when calling this part for using the photo library ,my app release errors

```
-(void)enterPhotoLib
{

 UIImagePickerController *imagepickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 [imagepickerController setDelegate:self];
 [imagepickerController setAllowsEditing:YES];
 [imagepickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
 [self presentModalViewController:imagepickerController animated:YES];
}
```

if I have any errors in these codes ,please answer me 
Thank you very much

Comment: what are the errors?  do these errors appear in your console?

Comment: If you can provide snapshot of the error you are getting it would be easy for me to tell you how to rectify this. At present i am seeing you have written presentModalViewController which is deprecated in iOS6 and above may be that is an issue but as you are saying you have an issue in iOS5 if you can provide me the error description then i can help you out more.